# Post destination receive put data 2 times in parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post, httparty

I'm developping a post to a callback url in Ruby on Rails and use the Httparty library for this, I receive the post perfectly on the url but it seems that rails convert the data that is pushed to the url 2 times to parameters. Here is the code that I use to do the call :

```
@result = HTTParty.post("http://localhost:3000/mailchimp/callback/", 
          :body => { 
            :data => {
              :title => 'This is the screen name'}
          }.to_json,
          :headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' } )
```

In the logs of the receiving application I got this :

```
Parameters: {"mailchimp"=>{"controller"=>"mailchimp", "action"=>"callback", "data"=>{"title"=>"This is the screen name"}}, "data"=>{"title"=>"This is the screen name"}}
```

You see directly that I have 2 times the data parameters, once in the controller hash and once in the normal parameters hash. How does this come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the ParamsWrapper module https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb

This is enabled by default in your rails app by the initializer `config/wrap_parameters.rb`

Comment: Ok thanks, I putted wrap_parameters false on top of my controller.